# Azure IOT Hub security token generation using mbed

Tags: azure, security, mbed

We are connecting to the Azure IOT Hub with security credentials created with Device Explorer.  However, since these credentials expire, our IOT devices need the capability to generate the credential periodically.

Our device is running under `mbed` so we are trying to use the `mbed` libraries in C++ to generate the signature.

From the Azure instructions:

> The security token has the following format: `SharedAccessSignature sig={signature-string}&se={expiry}&skn={policyName}&sr={URL-encoded-resourceURI}`

We have created a routine to generate the signature and the complete security token.  However, the connection is rejected when we use this value.  From testing different values, we can tell that it is the signature field that is the problem.

Our code is:

```
unsigned char   inputVal[90];
unsigned char   outputVal[60];

string GenerateSasToken (string resourceUri, string key, int expiryInSecs)
{
string *expiryStr;
const mbedtls_md_info_t *md_info;
string          *stringToSign;
std::vector<uint8_t>   keyVector;
string          *sasKey;
string          *password;

md_info = mbedtls_md_info_from_string("SHA256");

expiryStr = new string("1552139574");

stringToSign = new string();
*stringToSign = UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + *expiryStr;

logInfo("encode url: %s size: %d", stringToSign->data(), stringToSign->size());

mts::Text::base642bin(key, keyVector);
memcpy (inputVal, stringToSign->data(), stringToSign->size());
logInfo("input: key vector size: %d string size: %d", keyVector.size(), stringToSign->size());

mbedtls_md_hmac(md_info, keyVector.data(), keyVector.size(), inputVal, stringToSign->size(), outputVal);

sasKey = new(string);
*sasKey = mts::Text::bin2base64(outputVal, keyVector.size()); // sizeof(outputVal));

logInfo("sas token: %s", sasKey->data());

password = new(string);
*password = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "&sig=" + UrlEncode(sasKey->data()) + "&se=" + *expiryStr;
logInfo("password: %s", password->data());


delete sasKey;
delete password;
delete expiryStr;
delete stringToSign;
    return *password;
}
```

Any suggestions on what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe show some things you have tried that made you conclude it was the signature field. Need some more info to help

Comment: The strings generated from device explorer are of the form: SharedAccessSignature sr=OurHUBname.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fuf2f-ijd7-w63r-bndt&sig=pHrX9G6LQKhia5UYztjrpg%2FWweo3JvHcLJQcLxfYkp0%3D&se=1552139574     We have replaced just the signature portion with values that we have generated and the results now fail.

Comment: Why not use the Azure IoT Hub Device SDK? https://os.mbed.com/users/AzureIoTClient/. Alternatively, follow this JavaScript implementation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#security-token-structure, there should be one for C in the IoT Hub Device SDK as well.

Comment: I updated the project to use the Azure IoT Hub SDK as suggested and this worked fine.  I was hesitant to do that originally as it seemed to contain a lot of the same libraries that I was already using from mbed. However, there is obviously some difference as this worked great.  Thanks @evilSnobu